# Do Australian universities pay expenses to attend a faculty interview?

Tags: interview, australia

I have been invited for an interview for a lecturer position at a university in Australia. I am based in Europe at the moment. It is not expicitly clear, at least to me, in the invitation email that they will pay for the travelling and accommodation expenses, whether in full or in part. I thought I should ask them for clarifications, but I am not sure how to ask it, and perhaps it is better to find out more about the custom before asking.

Comment: Just ask them who makes the travel arrangements and who pays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is 'yes'. I know some colleagues who were invited for an interview for a lecturer position at an Australian university and they were indeed reimbursed for all their travel+accommodation+food+visa procedure expenses for the trip. The reimbursement was not conditional on if they would accept the job if offered or not. It was also written clearly on their invitation letters (needed for their Australian visa application) that they would be reimbursed all these expenses.
However, you must NOT assume anything. It is going to be a good amount of money travelling from Europe to Australia, and you must clarify about your reimbursement.

Comment: Yes, always get these things "in writing". I once moved 3000 miles with a (written!) promise of moving expenses paid, but at the far end they didn't want to, by default, until I scrounged-up that piece of paper.

Comment: I have a different experience.  A colleague of mine was interviewed over Skype.  Given the current state of Australian universities, I doubt they will pay for your 'lovely' trip from Europe!

Comment: @user35582, if an Australian university goes interviewing candidates, they must have made sure to secure funding to invite candidates over! I would just get it specified (in writing, as paul garrett emphasised) to avoid any confusion.

Comment: @John, you must work for a rich university!  Usually, the university will pay for relocation if they make the offer.

Comment: hI don't work in Australia. But I have worked in a university there in the past and I know the system at least generally. They do want to hire overseas candidates. And no overseas candidate, especially an early stage academic, would go all the way to Australia on his/her own expense to finally find out they didn't get the job! So the universities do have to pay the candidates' travel expenses. As I said, the OP must confirm this in writing as a general common sense.